# Getting error:No adapter attached; skipping layout in recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, adapter

I tried to fetch the json values from url and shows in listview with adapter in recylerview. but the listview is empty and getting this error 'No adapter attached; skipping layout'. When I tried with the below code its working

```
for (int i = index; i < end; i++) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Name " + i);
    mUsers.add(user);
}
```

Here is my part of code, if needed I'll upload complete code

```
public class OtherNews extends AppCompatActivity {

JSONArray jsonarray;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private List<User> mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter();

    new DownloadJSON().execute();

    mUserAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            Log.e("haint", "Load More");
            mUsers.add(null);
            mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1);
            //Load more data for reyclerview
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("haint", "Load More 2");
                    //Remove loading item
                    mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
                    mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());
                    //Load data
                    int index = mUsers.size();
                    int end = index + 20;
                    for (int i = index; i < end; i++) {
                        User user = new User();
                        user.setName("Name " + i);
                        user.setEmail("alibaba" + i + "@gmail.com");
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }
                    mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mUserAdapter.setLoaded();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private static final String TAG = "";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("http://xxxxxxxxx.in/projects/falcon/getallnews.php?page=2");
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("news");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    User user = new User();
                    String title = jsonobject.getString("title");
                    user.setName(title);
                    mUsers.add(user);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "someOther)");
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
    }
}
```

I get the value in this line of code, but couldn't set in list view.

```
String title = jsonobject.getString("title");
user.setName(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is exactly like it sounds, an adapter is not being attached when it needs it. You don't attach it until `onPostExecute`. Just attach it right from the beginning:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter();
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
```

As you modify the adapter in other parts of the code, your RecyclerView will update automatically, so long as you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or some related method.